# how to know if certain GET param is expected in a landing page?

Tags: url, url-parameters

I'm including certain param into the URL but I'm unsure if this landing page is supporting or expecting such GET parameters... Is there a way to know if at some point this will be read/used by the page? The param is: `s_rtid`

I already tried to find it by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> but no look.

Comment: You can try with the network tab in your browser's dev tools and look for any requests that include the s_rtid URL parameter. If the parameter is being sent in a request, it is likely that the page is expecting or using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a querystring e.g. example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2, and the page is not expecting those keys, then the page will load as if they weren't there.

However if the page *is* expecting those keys then the behaviour *may* be different depending on the code underlying those pages.  i.e. it may be coded to ignore incorrect values or it may be coded to behave a particular way if they are correct or not correct.

If it is not your site, about the only way to know for sure would be to either test it or ask the site owner.